# Add placeholders to ng-grid

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-grid

I have an editable ng-grid.  How can I add placeholders to empty cells (they should disappear when cells are edited)?

I know it is possible with input tags:

```
<input type="text" placeholder='Type something here'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`editableCellTemplate`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/).  For example:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  data: 'myData',
  enableCellSelection: true,
  enableRowSelection: false,
  enableCellEdit: true,
  columnDefs: [{
    field: 'name',
    displayName: 'Name',
    enableCellEdit: false
  }, {
    field: 'age',
    enableCellEdit: true,
    editableCellTemplate: '<input placeholder="Type something here" ng-input="COL_FIELD" ng-model="COL_FIELD" />'
  }]
};
```

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/x4Xhd0?p=preview

---

If you want the placeholder text to be visible when the cell is not being edited, you could create a custom (not editable) `cellTemplate` that displays the placeholder text instead of null values:

```
  cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text>{{COL_FIELD || "Type something here"}}</span></div>',
  editableCellTemplate: '<input ng-input="COL_FIELD" ng-model="COL_FIELD" placeholder="Type something here"/>'
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the placeholder appear before the user clicks on a cell?

Comment: i guess you could define a regular cell template, that coalesces the cell value with the placeholder text.